# Mathematica: Redefine multiplication so that 0*(-Inf) = 0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, undefined, logarithm, infinity, entropy

In my Mathematica program, I do some entropy calculations and I want to use this convention: `Log[0]*0 = 0.` Is there a clean way to do it or I have to write my own function?

Inspired by http://tinyurl.com/9d8r4rt I tried things like this:

```
Unprotect[Times];
Times[0,  -Infinity] := 0;
Protect[Times];
```

But it doesn't seem to work in my case. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I take the view, unhelpful to you right now, that if you don't understand how to subvert Mathematica's evaluation process you almost certainly shouldn't.  If, for example, you either (partially) redefine multiplication or `Log[]`, or provide `Up/Down/Own` values for `0` you'll want to be very certain about the impact on every other operation you use Mathematica for while it is in an unclean state.  Far safer and more straightforward to define your own function for your entropy calculations and to implement the desired simplification within its scope.

Answer (score 0):

I support High Performance Mark's statement above.  Nevertheless this is an interesting question because the answer is nontrivial.

You would need:

```
Unprotect[DirectedInfinity];

DirectedInfinity /: Log[0] 0 := 0
```

You need `DirectedInfinity` because:

```
Log[0] // FullForm
```

> ```
> DirectedInfinity[-1]
> ```

And you need an UpValue, made using `TagSet`, to override the default reaction to `-∞ * 0`, because UpValues are tried before other definitions.